# template function for multiple containers and data types

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

I want to create a template function that I can use with different containers type like vector, deque or list and that I can call it with different data types ( integers , double or string), I've searched but could'n't find an answer , I've tried doing it like this, but I'm getting errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
template <typename C>
void printvec(const C& numbers1)
//void printvec(container C<typename C::valuetype T>)
{
    //C &numbers1;
    for(auto i=0; i < numbers1.size(); ++i)
        cout<<&numbers1<<endl;
    //typename C<A>::iterator itr;
    //for ( itr=numbers1.begin();itr != numbers1.end(); ++itr)
      //  cout<<*itr<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vint{2,4,6,8,9,3};
    vector<double> vdouble{5.8, 6.7, 7.3};
    vector<string> vstring {"alex", "bbb", "cccc"};
    list<int> ls{1,2,3,4,5};
    printvec(vint );
    printvec(vdouble);
    printvec(vstring);
    printvec(ls);
        return 0;
}
```

so, what is the right way to do it, please?

Comment: [This](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/) might be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have pointed out why you should use a library function and why you are reinventing the wheel. Here is how you should have written it, if you want to do it.

Containers are not specified in terms of abstract base-classes but a generic interface that specifies required syntax and expected semantics of syntactical constructions (those things are called concepts). The most general is [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container), a more specialized one is [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer). If you accept a `SequenceContainer` as a template argument you must constrain code that uses the template argument to those requirements. In your case:

```
template<typename SequenceContainer>
void print(const SequenceContainer& seq)
{
  // being able to use range-for loops 
  // is a consequence of being a SequenceContainer
  for(auto& i : seq) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // alternatively
  using std::begin; // enable ADL fallback for arrays
  using std::end;
  for(auto it = begin(seq); it != end(seq); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Writing good template code is not for the faint of heart, so you might
want to consider getting a better understanding of basic C++ first.

Answer (score 3):

No real need to make a function out of this, the standard library already has all the tools you need for this:

```
 std::copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),
     std::ostream_iterator(cout,"\n"));
```

If you have C++11 at your disposal, use `std::begin(vec)` instead of `vec.begin()` and the same for `end` - it is more general as @AndyProwl correctly points out.

Comment: I would suggest using `begin(vec)` and `end(vec)` rather than the member functions, so it could work on C-style arrays as well

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to write your own function that iterates over a generic container, then this is probably the simplest way that works with any standard container:

```
template <typename C>
void print(const C& c)
{
    for (auto const& e : c) 
    { 
        cout << e << endl; 
    }
}
```

However, as [us2012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1865077/us2012) correctly pointed out, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why the standard library has algorithms like [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).  You pass a starting and ending iterator instead of the container itself.  The templated function you pass as the third argument takes care of the work.