# use template to print all the data of any container

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I plan to write a function which can print all the data of any container. In other words, I can use with different containers type like vector, deque or list and that I can call it with different data types ( integers , double or string).
The template function can pass the compiler, but I do not know how to call it.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <typename C, template <typename C> class M>
void print(M<C> data){
typename M<C>::iterator it;
for(it=data.template begin();it!=data.template end();++it){
    cout<<*it<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
list<int> data;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    data.push_back(i);
}
print<int>(data);   //compile error
print<int, list>(data);   //compile error
 return 0;
}
```

error message:
main.cpp:35:20: error: no matching function for call to 'print(std::list&)'
main.cpp:35:20: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:21:6: note: template class M> void print(M)

some related threads:
[template function for multiple containers and data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077575/template-function-for-multiple-containers-and-data-types)
http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/

Comment: `std::list` has more than one template parameter. You shouldn't be giving the template arguments explicitly either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `std::list` actually has more than one template parameter (the second parameter is the allocator). Moreover, there is no need for `print` to take two template parameters; you can simply parameterize it over the overall container type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <typename C>
void print(const C &data){
    for(auto it=begin(data);it!=end(data);++it){
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    list<int> data;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        data.push_back(i);
    }
    print(data);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12e48bd1981e2c04).

As pointed out in the other answer, if you can use C++11 features, a range-for loop is better than the explicit iterator use above. If you can't (which means no `auto` or `std::begin` or `std::end` either), then:

```
template <typename C>
void print(const C &data){
    for(typename C::const_iterator it=data.begin();it!= data.end();++it){
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Note that since we take `data` by const reference, we need to use `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

Using c++11 you can simplify it to:

```
template <typename C>
void print(const C &data){
    for (auto &elem : data)
        cout << elem << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

and call it with `print(data)`. You could also use `std::for_each` or [copy it directly into cout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260709/2037136).